# Attempt to Add Instance of Class Fails

Tags: c#, vb.net, hid

I'm trying to work with a C# USB HID library (Mike O'Brien's open-source HIDLibrary) from my VB.NET application. I was able to make calls to methods in one of the classes easily. However, another method I'd like to call into in a different class isn't working. I can't access it directly by invoking the namespace and class name like I did for the other class, as VS complains "that a reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference". The class is public, so I think I *should" be able to call into it, but OK, so I try to add an object reference in my app, and it complains "Overload resolution failed because no "New" is accessible". The two classes (one of which "works", the other of which doesn't) appear to be set up virtually identically: they're both declared public, as are both of the methods I'm trying to call into.

I'm still a bit new to C#, and OOP in general, so pardon the newb question.

The full classes are pretty big, so I'm going to attempt to only include the "relevant" parts, but if I'm leaving something out, please let me know.

How the class I'd like to access is defined:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HidLibrary
{
    public class HidDevice : IHidDevice
    { ...
```

And the method itself I'm attempting to call:

```
public bool ReadFeatureData(out byte[] data, byte reportId = 0)
```

The way I've set up my VB.NET app to call into this dll:

```
Imports HidLibrary

Public Class DeviceIDTest

    Dim HIDDeviceObj As New HidLibrary.HidDevice
```

And finally my attempt at a method call:

```
        If HidDeviceObj.ReadFeatureData(InBuff, reportID) Then
            Return InBuff
        Else
            Return False
        End If
```

Comment: You can always check open-source of that library. But based on the fact that `Overload resolution failed because no "New" is accessible` - I think class have public constructor(`New`) but it needs some parameters. Other option: there must be some other class or some static method in same class which will create an instance

Comment: On this line `Dim HIDDeviceObj As New HidLibrary.HidDevice` try typing open bracket at the end and see what variables it's looking for the in the `New()` popup.

Comment: @Neal In VS15, all an open bracket gets you is an auto-completed closed bracket, unfortunately.

Comment: @nobby I had a look at the constructor for that class and it looks like it wants 2 strings: `HidDevice(string devicePath, string description = null)` Have you tried putting strings in there?

Comment: @Neal Do you mean in my method call? So stop trying to declare a new instance of the HidDevice class, and instead make my method call: `If HidLibrary.HidDevice(ControllerString, "").ReadFeatureData(InBuff, reportID) Then`  If that's what you mean, tried it, and get a "HidDevice is a class type and cannot be used in an expression" error.

Comment: No I think you still need to declare the object HIDDeviceObj. Does it work if you change that line to: `Dim HIDDeviceObj As New HidLibrary.HidDevice(ControllerString, "")`

Comment: @Neal Ah, gotcha, unfortunately, no, still gives me the "Overload resolution failed because No 'New" is accessible" error  `Public Class DeviceIDTest
    Dim ControllerString

    Dim HIDDeviceObj As New HidLibrary.HidDevice(ControllerString, "")`

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for [`HidDevice`](https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary/blob/master/src/HidLibrary/HidDevice.cs) is [`internal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx), so it can only be called from other classes in the HidLibrary assembly, which is why you get the "Overload resolution failed because no "New" is accessible" error.  Since the class is public, that probably implies that there is some other way to create instances.  I have never used this library, but from a quick glance it looks like maybe you are supposed to use one of the static methods on [`HidDevices`](https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary/blob/master/src/HidLibrary/HidDevices.cs), i.e. `GetDevice` or one of the `Enumerate` methods, to access instances of `HidDevice`.

For example (completely untested code!):

```vb
Dim data() As Byte
For Each device In HidDevices.Enumerate()
    If device.ReadFeatureData(data) Then
        ' Do something with data?
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Ah, this makes much more sense! That HidDevices.Enumerate method is the one that I referred to that IS working. I'll give that a shot. Thanks!